# False translation from hql to sql

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpa-2.0, jpql

In my (hql) query I have the following `where-clause`:

```
LOWER( f_umlautfree2( replace(user.lastName, ' ', '')||replace(user.firstName, ' ', '')  ) ) LIKE LOWER ('%'||( f_umlautfree2( replace(replace(:name, ',', ''), ' ', '') ) )||'%')
```

If I let print the "real" sql query out, it is "translated" this way:

```
lower(idmanlight.f_umlautfree2((replace(user0_.lastName||' '||'')||replace(user0_.firstName||' '||'')))) like lower(('%'||idmanlight.f_umlautfree2(replace(replace('%Croci%'||','||'')||' '||''))||'%'))
```

causing an error something like "No function replace(text) exist..."

Why all the `,` (between the function's brackets) are replaced with `||`?

This is the complete hql query:

```
select
    distinct user.dbId,
    user.lastName,
    user.firstName
from
    User user  LEFT join user.permissions
where
    LOWER( f_umlautfree2( replace(user.lastName, ' ', '')||replace(user.firstName, ' ', '')  ) ) LIKE LOWER ('%'||( f_umlautfree2( replace(replace(:name, ',', ''), ' ', '') ) )||'%')
and
    (user.employee IS NOT NULL OR user.lecturer IS NOT NULL OR user.ethRelated IS NOT NULL OR user.pdbGuest IS NOT NULL)
and
    user.valid = :valid  
order by
    user.lastName, user.firstName asc
```

and this is the complete resulting sql query:

```
select
     distinct user0_.dbId as col_0_0_,
     user0_.lastName as col_1_0_,
     user0_.firstName as col_2_0_
from
     idmanlight.NETHZ_USER user0_
left outer join
     idmanlight.NETHZ_USER_PERMISSION permission1_
         on user0_.dbId=permission1_.NETHZ_USER_dbId
left outer join
     idmanlight.PERMISSION permission2_
         on permission1_.permissions_dbId=permission2_.dbId
where
     (
         lower(idmanlight.f_umlautfree2((replace(user0_.lastName||' '||'')||replace(user0_.firstName||' '||'')))) like lower(('%'||idmanlight.f_umlautfree2(replace(replace('%Croci%'||','||'')||' '||''))||'%'))
     )
     and (
         user0_.employee is not null
         or user0_.lecturer is not null
         or user0_.ethRelated is not null
         or user0_.pdbGuest is not null
     )
     and user0_.valid=?
 order by
     user0_.lastName,
     user0_.firstName asc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HQL does [not support](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-exp-functions) `replace` function. You should register it with [Dialect.registerFunction()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/Dialect.html#registerFunction%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunction%29).

*([here](http://marzapol.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/custom-function-is-hibernate/) is an example of how to do it)*